# How to prove that $\int_0^1 x^{-x}\text{d}x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-n}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I've been trying to prove that
$$
\int_0^1 x^{-x}\text{d}x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-n}
$$
Mathematica told me that's true, but I don't know how to solve it. Is there any way to prove it?

Comment: It's a known result

Comment: Oh thanks, I'm just new in mathematics...